# Ace Double identification - amateur kidney transplant

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know what the novel is called?  My memory of it is fading, but it seems to me that in the beginning the main character had a flying car and was trying to get a kidney for his girlfriend.  I think if he gets it he is able to "install" it himself (because of advanced technology.)  I think there is much more to the story but that's all I can still remember.

On multiple occasions I have searched for sites that have Ace Double science fiction books, but was unable to recognize the cover or any plot summaries I may have found.

Comment: How long ago did you read it? I don't suppose you have any recollection of what was on the other half of the Ace Double?

Comment: It may have been over 40 years ago.  Unfortunately, I can't remember what was on the other side.